# fancybox: finding anchor from which fancybox was called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, fancybox

Inside fancybox window I would like to retrieve html element (anchor probably) from which fancybox was called. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this. I need to pass onStart function:

```
onStart(selectedArray, selectedIndex, selectedOpts)
```

and then call:

```
selectedArray[selectedIndex].orig
```